# Changing YouTube-DL Default Save Location for Embedded use in Python Script

Tags: ubuntu, youtube-dl

`YouTube-DL` saves by default in the working directory, unless you specifically direct it otherwise in the `youtube-dl.conf` file. However, this file doesn't exist on install, and I'm having a lot of trouble creating it.

I'm running an Ubuntu 16.04 LAMP stack server on Digital Ocean.

I tried creating `youtube-dl.conf` under `/usr/local/etc` and then added this to it: `--o ~/html/media/audio/%(title)s` but that does nothing.

I tried the solution in [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237388/setup-youtube-dl-destination-to-downloads) answer:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/youtube-dl/
echo "-o ~/html/media/audio/%(title)s" > ~/.config/youtube-dl/config
```

And it worked without any issues, but I can't find where it made the directory, and either way it doesn't work.

I can't simply do something like `youtube-dl -o "~/Desktop/%(title)s.%(ext)s" 'youtube file url'` because I'm using `youtube-dl` from a Python script, and not from command line. Running the above command without a URL doesn't work. [Related askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/373336/where-does-youtube-dl-download-youtube-files).

Can anyone help me out? The working directory is `/var/www/html`, but I need it to save in `/var/www/html/media/audio`. Still new to Ubuntu. Thank you!

[Youtube-DL Github Configuration Section](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#configuration)

Edit: Using the answer by @phihag below, I added this:

```
subprocess.check_call(['youtube-dl', '--output', '/var/www/html/media/audio/%(title)s.%(ext)s', url])
```

But this is saving the file in `mkv` and I need it in `mp3` format. I've tried something like:

```
subprocess.check_call(['youtube-dl', '--audio-format', 'mp3', '--output', '/var/www/html/media/audio/%(title)s.%(ext)s', url])
```

And other variations, but I get something like this error:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['youtube-dl', '--extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --output '/var/www/html/media/audio/%(title)s', 'url']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

These are the options I was previously using that I'm now trying to emulate using the `subprocess`:

```
    ydl_opts = {
        'fixup': 'detect_or_warn',
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'extractaudio': True,
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '320',
        }],
        'logger': MyLogger(),
        'progress_hooks': [my_hook],
    }
```

Using these options above does not allow for changing the default location. That has to be done on a case-by-case basis through command line, each time you want to download, or you need to use the config file (to my understanding. I haven't seen any examples in my searching where someone can specify the default save location through the API in a script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to write a configuration file; you can set the output template from python as well:

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {
    'outtmpl': '/var/www/html/media/audio/%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'extractaudio': True,
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '320',
    }],
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'])
```

Comment: That worked!  The only issues with this are that 1) It's also still saving files in the current directory, and 2) It's saving audio files as `mkv`. I tried `subprocess.check_call(['youtube-dl', '--audio-format', 'bestaudio/best', url])` after but it says `WARNING: Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv.` Any Idea how to change that?

Comment: 1) Which files get saved in the current directory when you run the exact code in this question? For instance, the example code you post later does not make a lot of sense. Please make sure that if you run something, you post the exact code you're running somewhere. A [gist](https://gist.github.com/) works fine in a pinch. Asking a new question with the full code may also be justified.
2) Again, please post actual reproducible code, including a test URL. You can use `--format` to select a download format, but likely something else is wrong here.

Comment: Thanks, the other save location was my error and I fixed it. Currently I'm trying to add other commands to the `subprocess.check_call` and it's not working. I edited the question earlier. If you prefer, I can accept this answer and start a new question.

Comment: Wait, what? You were already using the API and switched to subprocess? This does not make any sense.

Comment: Updated the answer to a proper API one. If you can use the API, you most definitely should do so, it is much more powerful.

Comment: Thanks. You seem to be familiar with youtube-dl so maybe you'll know this. Each time I use `outtmpl` for audio-only extractions, I get this error: `youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: audio conversion failed: file:mp3: Invalid argument`. It doesn't happen when I use `outtmpl` for only video and audio+video extractions.

Comment: I wrote much of youtube-dl, so that's why I'm somewhat familiar with it. Again, please post your [complete](http://sscce.org/) code.

Comment: Your solution worked. I don't know why I was always getting the audio conversion error before, but I'm not now. Thanks for writing `youtube-dl`.